# Display response object from GET request on backend in react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am still figuring React out and have a question. I want to display some data that I am getting back from my mLab database. When I make the request in Postman to test request i get back the object full of data and now I want to display that data in my component.

**Backend/server.js:**

```
//this is tested and works in postman
app.get('/logs', function(req, res) {
 user: req.user;
 res.json();
});
```

**React action:**

```
export const GET_DATA_SUCCESS = 'GET_DATA_SUCCESS';
export const GET_DATA_TRIGGERED = 'GET_DATA_TRIGGERED';
export const GET_DATA_FAILURE = 'GET_DATA_FAILURE';

export function getData() {
const promise = fetch('http://localhost:8080/logs');
return {
  onRequest: GET_DATA_TRIGGERED,
  onSuccess: GET_DATA_SUCCESS,
  onFailure: GET_DATA_FAILURE,
  promise,
};
}
```

**Component where I want to display:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Link, Redirect, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { getData } from '../actions/memory';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class oldMemory extends React.Component {

oldSearch(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 this.props.getData();
}


render() {

return(
  <div className="old-info">
  <Link to="/main"><h3 className="title-journey">Travel Journal</h3></Link>
   <h4>Retrieve a Memory</h4>
   <p className="get-info">Look back on an old place you have visited and 
   reminisce.</p>
  <input className="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" 
  />
   <button onClick={this.oldSearch.bind(this)}>Get</button>
   // would like data to show up here
  </div>
  )
  }
  }

  export default connect(null, { getData })(oldMemory)
```

Comment: What data do you want to display? Do you get them from getData?

Comment: I want to display the data that is coming back from the database. The res.json response in the server.js file gives back an object with the data I want to display. I thought after that you have to make the front end then grab that data from the back end to display it. Which is what getData() is suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a state to store the data and set the state after the getData promise is resolved. Then, in the render method, i map the state data to div elements and display them in the the component.

```
// I assume your result of get Data is an array of 
// objects {id: number,date: string, memory: string} 
// and that getData is a promise

class OldMemory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  oldSearch = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.getData().then(data => {
    // if data is null, or undefined set it to an empty array
    this.setState({ data: data || [] });
   })
  }

  render() {
    // build data to div elements for display
    const memories = this.state.data.map(d => <div>{d.date} - {d.memory}</div>)
    return(
      <div className="old-info">
      <Link to="/main"><h3 className="title-journey">Travel Journal</h3></Link>
       <h4>Retrieve a Memory</h4>
       <p className="get-info">Look back on an old place you have visited and 
       reminisce.</p>
      <input className="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" 
      />
       <button onClick={this.oldSearch}>Get</button>
       // would like data to show up here
       <div id="display-data">
        { memories }
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { getData })(OldMemory)
```

Comment: So I tried implementing this and I get a "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error.

Comment: Data is an array of objects and getData() is a promise correct.

Comment: @JontheNerd Did you set default value of this.state.data to [] in the constructor?